# Hi, I started gogland. I can't running

Tags: go, ide, goland

I started gogland. I have a running problem.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you much pick a file in order for the configuration to work. Specifically it must be a file containing the `func main()` declaration.

You can use the Run Type: Package instead of file in order to run a package.

For example, if your main is under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/dlsniper/demo/cmd/mycmd/main.go` then you need to use `github.com/dlsniper/demo/cmd/mycmd` in order to run it.

Moreover, from the screenshot you've pasted, it seems like you are not under a valid Go workspace. Please see here what a Go Workspace is and how to create one: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces

Finally, if you prefer a visual guide for this, please have a look at this video on how to create and use Run Configurations in Gogland: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko-wKntCLjg

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17369048)

Comment: @NickWeaver thank you, I've edited my response based on your feedback. Please let me know if I can make it any better. Thank you.